# Parse Javascript - Relation is not a function

Tags: parse-platform

I'm trying to understand how relation works and i did wrote this simple script:

```
var Parse = require('parse/node');

Parse.initialize('myAppId');
Parse.serverURL = 'http://localhost:1337/parse';

var userQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
userQuery.equalTo('username', 'the_username');

userQuery.find()
    .then(user => {
        return user;
    })
    .then(user => {
        var Systems = Parse.Object.extend("systems");
        var systemQuery = new Parse.Query(Systems);
        systemQuery.equalTo('customer', 'myCustomer');

        systemQuery.find()
            .then(system => {
                var relation = user.relation('systems_ref'); // HERE I GET RELATION IS NOT A FUNC
                relation.add(system);
                console.log('Adding relation');

                user.save()
                    .then(response => console.log('user saved'))
                    .catch(error => console.log('Error saving', error));
            }).catch(error => console.log('Error find system', error));
    });
```

But in the line where i try to get `user.relation` i have the error "Relation is not a function".

I have look others example on how to create a relation, but i dont see difference in my code...

I have the user (that is a sublcass of ParseObject), and on it i'm trying to access relation method...

Answer (score 1):

You may use it as follows:
To add the Post to User with the JavaScript SDK:


*var user = Parse.User.current();

var relation = user.relation("posts");

relation.add(post);

user.save();*

Comment: maybe you are not getting user obecjt where you are calling relation for this. you can console and find if it is ok or not.

Comment: I've placed console.log everywhere and all works... i get the User back and is an instance of ParseUser... Maybe with User.current() will works, but i will need to do this in the "Administration" page i'm building, so i cand use the current user, because i have to add relation to others user. I will user array of Pointer if this do not works :(